# AWS Cognito Boto3 Error on Confirm Device: Invalid device key given

Tags: django, python-3.x, boto3, amazon-cognito

I have been creating a AWS Cognito flow with Python, Django and Boto3 with MFA enables.

My authentication flow is the following:

**initiate_auth**: called on an django rest endpoint

```
response = client.initiate_auth(
            ClientId=settings.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
            AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
            AuthParameters={
                'USERNAME': email,
                'SECRET_HASH': get_secret_hash(email),
                'PASSWORD': password,
            }
        )

if "ChallengeName" in response:
            data["mfa"] = True
            data["session"] = response["Session"]
```

**respond_to_auth_challenge**: called on a seperate django rest endpoint

```
response = client.respond_to_auth_challenge(
            ClientId=settings.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
            ChallengeName='SMS_MFA',
            Session=session,
            ChallengeResponses={
                'USERNAME': email,
                'SMS_MFA_CODE': code,
                'SECRET_HASH': get_secret_hash(email),
            }
        )
```

based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499526/device-password-verifier-challenge-response-in-amazon-cognito-using-boto3-and-wax#new-answer) I wanted to implement the confirm device so MFA is skipped upon next login. So after the respond to auth challenge I have this code:

```
device_key = response['AuthenticationResult']['NewDeviceMetadata']['DeviceKey']
        device_group_key = response['AuthenticationResult']['NewDeviceMetadata']['DeviceGroupKey']

        device_password, device_secret_verifier_config = generate_hash_device(device_group_key, device_key)

        device = client.confirm_device(
            AccessToken=response["AuthenticationResult"]["AccessToken"],
            DeviceKey=device_key,
            DeviceSecretVerifierConfig=device_secret_verifier_config,
            DeviceName=email
        )
```

But I always get the

> Unknown error An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the ConfirmDevice operation: Invalid device key given.

Can anyone help on why this happens?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a something that worked for me.

In your challange response, you need to pass the username from the response for the `initial_auth`

In your code that should be stored at `response["Username"]`

then when calling the `respond_to_auth_challenge` you will use this parameter

```
response = client.respond_to_auth_challenge(
            ClientId=settings.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
            ChallengeName='SMS_MFA',
            Session=session,
            ChallengeResponses={
                'USERNAME': username, // response["Username"] <--------
                'SMS_MFA_CODE': code,
                'SECRET_HASH': get_secret_hash(email),
            }
        )
```

I wish it was better documented on AWS or they would have at least a better error message.

That solved the problem for me.